# Sorting same author two papers in bibliography with biblatex

Tags: biblatex

If I have several papers written by the same author, I would like to sort them by the order of year then titles. But the default result is by titles. I have tried by adding `sorting=nyt`, but it does not work. [image]

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@ARTICLE{Euclid,
  author =       {Euclid},
  title =        {Elements},
  journal =      {Geometry},
  year =         {2000},
}
@ARTICLE{Euclidc,
  author =       {Euclid},
  title =        {Correction to ``Elements''},
  journal =      {Geometry},
  year =         {2010},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage[
  bibencoding=utf8,
  backend=biber,
  hyperref=true,
  backref=true,
  backrefstyle=three,
  style=numeric-comp,
  sortcites,
%  sorting=nyt
  ]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
  Let us see~\cite{Euclid,Euclidc}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: With `sorting=nyt` I get the desired order. Did you rerun Biber after enabling the option?

Comment: @egreg I got an error msg `!undefined control sequence <argument> \blx@temp`.

Comment: Enable the `nyt` option, remove the `.bbl` file, rerun LaTeX, run Biber.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you enable the `sorting=nyt` option after having already produced a `.bbl` file, you'll get an error

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \blx@tempb
```

You can ignore it, which will happen if you're running LaTeX from the command line and hit return or your front-end runs LaTeX in noninteractive mode. If, instead, your TeX engine can't end the run, remove the old `.bbl` file.

Then run LaTeX again (just to be sure), run Biber and LaTeX again.